# Show a $p$-value is valid

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, p-value

This is an excercise from "Testing statistical hypotheses" (Lehmann & Romano).

> Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a sample space, $T$ a test statistic and **G** be a finite group of transformations (with $M$ elements) from $\mathcal{X}$  onto itself. Under the null-hypothesis the distribution of the random variable $X$ is invariant under the transformations in **G**. Let $$\hat{p}= \frac{1}{M}\sum_{g \in G}I_{\{T(gX) \geq T(X) \} }.$$ Show that $P(\hat{p} \leq u ) \leq u $ for $0 \leq u \leq 1$ under the null hypothesis.

I was thinking that $I_{\{T(gX) \geq T(X) \} }$ all have the same distribution under the null hypothesis and hence $\hat{p}$ should have a binomial distribution (is this correct?). I didn't manage to show the inequalty with this though. Does anybody know how one can prove it?

Kind regards,

Comment: The inequality $P(\hat{p} \leq \alpha) \leq \alpha$ also reminds me of the probability integral transform but I don't really see how/if one can use it in this case.

Comment: "I was thinking that [...] (is this correct?)". The events $\{T(gX)\ge T(X)\}$ are clearly dependent, even positively correlated: occurence of one event $\{T(gX)\ge T(X)\}$ makes others more likely. They moreover have different probabilities in general: for $g = e$, the event $\{T(gX)\ge T(X)\} = \{T(X)\ge T(X)\}$ is sure. So no, the distribution is not binomial in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the distribution of $\hat p$ is supported by $S := \{0,\frac1M, \frac2M,\dots,1\}$. Since  $$\mathrm P(\hat p\le u) = \mathrm P\Bigl(\hat p\le \frac{\lfloor M u\rfloor}M\Bigr),$$ it is enough to prove the statement for $u\in S$.

To prove the claim, we will use kind of "double counting" argument.

Let $u= \frac kM\in S$. What does $\hat p(x)\le u$ mean? It means that the value $T(x)$ is among the $k$ largest values in the orbit $O_x := \{hx, h\in G\}$ of $x$. That said, for any $x \in \mathcal X$, 
$$
\bigl|\{y\in O_x: \hat p(y)\le u \}\bigr|\le k.
$$
(In the orbit, there are no more than $k$ values, which are among the $k$ largest. There can be less: e.g. in $\{1,1,1,2,2,2\}$ there are only $3$ values which are among the $4$ largest.) In other words, 
$$
\sum_{h\in G} \mathbf 1_{\hat p(hx)\le u} \le k.
$$
Substitute $x=X$ and take the expectation:
$$
k\ge \mathrm E\left[\sum_{h\in G} \mathbf 1_{\hat p(hX)\le u}\right]  = \sum_{h\in G}\mathrm E\left[ \mathbf 1_{\hat p(hX)\le u}\right]\\
= \sum_{h\in G}\mathrm P\bigl(\hat p(hX)\le u\bigr) = \sum_{h\in G}\mathrm P\bigl(\hat p(X)\le u\bigr) = M\, \mathrm P\bigl(\hat p(X)\le u\bigr) 
$$
(in the penultimate equality we have used the invariance of distribution under $G$). Equivalently,
$$
\mathrm P(\hat p(X)\le u) \le \frac kM =u, 
$$
as required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm just wondering; if $\hat{p}(x)\leq u$ doesn't that mean that $T(x)$ is among the $k$ largest  values?

Comment: @user202542, sure, you're right, thanks, fixed.

Comment: Ok, I see! Nice proof!

Comment: A comment and a question... Comment first: I think the term "among the $k$ largest" is a bit confusing here (at least for me), because (at least for me) that term would allow ties, i.e. in the set $\{1,1,1,2,2,2\}$ I would say there are $6$ values among the $4$ largest. Now of course in this case we really mean "$T(x)$ is exceeded or tied by at most $k$ others". Not sure there's a good way to say it easily...

Comment: Question: Where in the proof did you use the fact that $G$ is a _group_?  If $G$ is just a finite _set_ of transformations, it is possible (I think) that $X$ is invariant under $G$ but the main statement is false, e.g. think of $|G|=1$ and it is a single rotation in such a way that $T(gx) < T(x)$ always, s.t. $\hat{p} \equiv 0$.  So IMHO the main statement is only provable if we incorporate the fact that $G$ is a group, and in particular, if $g \in G$ then $g^{-1} \in G$ also.

Comment: [cont'd] In particular, if $G$ is not a group, the "orbit" $O_x = Gx$ is still well defined but $\forall x: \bigl|\{y\in O_x: \hat p(y)\le u \}\bigr|\le k$ would not longer be true.  So this must be where the group aspect comes in...?  I would appreciate if you can comment more on this.  Perhaps I just misunderstood your proof, in which case my apologies. :)

Comment: @antkam, sorry for a late response: for some reason, I was not notified about your comments. Indeed, I do need the existence of inverse, as in my proof I am using implicitly the fact that $O_y = O_x$ whenever $y \in O_x$. Precisely, when I speak of "$k$ largest values", I use that they correspond to an orbit rather than to some $x$. Without that, the inequality $\bigl|\{y\in O_x: \hat p(y)\le u \}\bigr|\le k$ and hence the whole double counting argument would fail.